# Function continuous at $ (0,0) $ but not differentiable at $ (0,0) $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In a book I ran into the following problem:

Let $ f: \mathbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined as $ \displaystyle \frac{| x | y}{\sqrt {x ^ 2 + y ^ 2}} $ if $ (x , y) \neq (0,0) $ and $ 0 $ if $ (x, y) = (0,0) $.

They ask me to prove that $ f $ is continuous at $ (0,0) $, that it has all its directional derivatives in $ (0,0) $ but that $ f $ is not differentiable at $ (0,0) $, I It seems strange that it is continuous at that point but at the same time is not derivable. Is this correct? If so, how is it resolved?

Comment: Many functions can be continuous but not differentiable, consider $f(x) = |x|$ which is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: Why do you find that strange? Differentiability is stronger than continuity. Did you never see the example $f(x) = |x|$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, let us take the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$. In order to do so, notice that
\begin{align*}
y \leq |y| = \sqrt{y^{2}} \leq \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \Rightarrow \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{|x|y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} \leq |x|
\end{align*}
Similarly,

\begin{align*}
y\geq -|y| = - \sqrt{y^{2}} \geq -\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \Rightarrow \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\geq -1 \Rightarrow \frac{|x|y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\geq -|x|
\end{align*}

Due to the sandwich theorem, one concludes that $f$ is continuous. Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} = 0 = f(0,0)
\end{align*}

As to the directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ along $v = (a,b)$, we have the following definition
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f((0,0) + t(a,b)) - f(0,0)}{t} & = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(ta,tb)}{t}\\\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|ta|tb}{t\sqrt{t^{2}a^{2}+t^{2}b^{2}}}\\\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|a|b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} = \frac{|a|b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
\end{align*}

Moreover, according to the definition of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle f_{x}(0,0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t,0) - f(0,0)}{t} = 0\\\\
\displaystyle f_{y}(0,0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0,t) - f(0,0)}{t} = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Now suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. Then we could express
\begin{align*}
Df((0,0)) = (f_{x}(0,0),f_{y}(0,0)) = (0,0)
\end{align*}

Consequently, if we let $v = (a,b)$, the directional derivative along $v = (a,b)$ would be equal to
\begin{align*}
D_{v}f((0,0)) = \langle Df((0,0)),(a,b)\rangle = \langle (0,0),(a,b)\rangle = 0 \neq \frac{|a|b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction. Thus $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Once you've calculated the directional derivatives, since the result is not linear in $a$ and $b$, you can immediately conclude that the function is not differentiable, although it's probably good to spell it out as you did here.  (Warning: the converse is false; a function can have linear directional derivatives without even being continuous, and it can have linear directional derivatives and be continuous without being differentiable.  See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differentiable+map#DifferentiabilityOpposedToPartialDifferentiability for examples of each of these.)

Comment: Thanks for the enriching comment!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

The function is continuous at $(0,0)$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)$. So for this, you should look at the following limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

The function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if the tangent plane at $(0,0)$ provides a "good" approximation for $f(x,y)$ near $(0,0)$. You should calculate $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ to get the tangent plane.